# Tkinter does not show up

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, enthought

I downloaded Canopy and I would like to use `Tkinter` and for this, I disabled `pylab` and ran the program but still nothing showed up. Additionally, I tried tkinter on `jupyter` and same problem.

How can I make it work?

Here is my code :

```
import Tkinter as Tk

screen=Tk.Tk()
screen.title("Matplot Graphies")
screen.geometry("500x500")
```

I tried simple code to see GUI but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `mainloop()` method at the end.

```
import Tkinter as Tk

screen=Tk.Tk()
screen.title("Matplot Graphies")
screen.geometry("500x500")
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: when l use python , it shows without mainloop .thanks for help:).that is why l tried samething .my mistake

Comment: @ömersarı Some IDEs (like IDLE) calls it implicitly even if you don't call it yourself. Ideally, _you_ should call it.